# Exporting Google Ads Data To Specific Cell Range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-ads-api

I have an ads script which exports data to a sheet based on rules.

However, I only want to replace data within a certain cell range such as 'A2:J' within a Google sheet.

I know how to do this within spreadsheetApp script but unsure/struggling on Ads script/AWQL.

I have pasted the basics of the script below but really could do with insight into whether and how it is possible to push to a specific range.

```
function main(){

// Put your Google data sheet here
var sheetURL = '';

// Enter the tab name here
var tabName = '';

var QUERIES = [{'query' : 'SELECT Date, DayOfWeek, HourOfDay, Device, CampaignName, Impressions, Clicks, Cost, Conversions, ConversionValue ' +
                        'FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
            'WHERE Impressions > 0 ' +
                      'DURING TODAY',
                      //'DURING ' + dateRanges, 
            'spreadsheetUrl' : sheetURL,
            'tabName' : tabName,
            'reportVersion' : 'v201809'
           }            
          ];

//This is to gather the above query and push it to the spreadsheet stated above
  for(var i in QUERIES) {
    var queryObject = QUERIES[i];
    var query = queryObject.query;
    var spreadsheetUrl = queryObject.spreadsheetUrl;
    var tabName = queryObject.tabName;
    var reportVersion = queryObject.reportVersion;
    //Logger.log(spreadsheetUrl + " " + query);
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl);
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(tabName);
    var report = AdWordsApp.report(query, {apiVersion: reportVersion});
    report.exportToSheet(sheet);
  }
}
```

Comment: This report looks like it would fill in the first ten columns and that's column J.  So what's the problem?

Comment: @Cooper It does fill columns I want it to. However, it clears and replaces the whole sheet and not just data in columns A:J. So I was wanting to just replace a set range and not the whole sheet.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm wondering how about letting go ahead and do that in the same sheet every time and then just add the code to copy the data to the final sheet yourself and then you can more control over what the final report looks like.

Comment: @Cooper I was tempted to do that using either query or pushing the data on a schedule to a new sheet. (I have this set up for a much larger data set). I just thought I'd see if there is a way to maybe replace a certain range. I think its a bit more time researching... Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer:

Basically, it is not possible to export a `report` only to a certain range of the sheet directly. As you can see in the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/reference/adsapp/adsapp_report#exportToSheet_1), `exportToSheet(sheet)` only accepts a `sheet` as an argument, and there are no additional optional arguments to accomplish your purpose.

## Workaround:

As Cooper and yourself commented, you can export the report to another sheet, and from there [copy the desired range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) to your final sheet.

If you don't want to have this additional sheet around all the time, I'd  propose [creating a new sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname) every time you use `exportTosheet`, exporting the report to this newly created sheet, and finally [deleting this sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet) after it has been copied to the final sheet.

Also, since last November 2018, you should be using `AdsApp` instead of `AdWordsApp`, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/whats-new#november_27_2018).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the information. I appreciate the clear no confirmation, so I will utilise the other method. I have created a version with the updated AdsApp, just pasted the old one in but again cheers for the heads up.